# Server Side datatable crashes on processing

Tags: datatables

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#browseListings').DataTable({
           "processing":"true",
           "serverSide":"true",
           "ajax":"http://localhost//htdocs/index.php/admin/ajaxbrowse"
         });
    });
</script>

<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1" class="datable_table display" id="browseListings">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th><th>Country</th><th>Listing Type</th>   <th>Actions</th></tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

On the page load it correctly gives me the first 10 entries however when I pagniate it just hangs on "Processing". I know it returns data from the console in the same format as the first page so have I missed something? From the manual it doesn't look like you have to set Columns - it should just simply work??

Comment: There will undoubtedly be an error displayed in the console, please show it.

Comment: No errors in either JS console or firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue here was that draw needs to increase and I had hard coded it to 1! I was using my own custom server side script and had included draw but not set it to match the inbound (although have cast as int as suggested).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer